# Install CouchDB via Home Brew

Tags: homebrew, macos

I'm trying to install CouchDB using Homebrew but it gives me the following error:

```
Error: couchdb dependency spidermonkey was built with the following
C++ standard library: libstdc++ (from clang)

This is incompatible with the standard library being used
to build couchdb: libc++ (from clang)

Please reinstall spidermonkey using a compatible compiler.
hint: Check https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/C++-Standard-Libraries
```

I went to the given URL and yes: I am on Mavericks GM. 
I tried a complete reinstall of homebrew but that still gives me the same error.

But how can I reinstall Spidermonkey with libc++?

Comment: I think you need to ask the person who set up the homebrew receipe (I know the issues with Macports re the two std C++ libraries andI would guess this is similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have filed a [bug report](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/23332) on the homebrew project. The problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with those specific packages, but based on similar experience with other packages, I'd do

```
brew rm spidermonkey
brew install spidermonkey
```

and then try to install `couchdb` again.